# How to fix insecure-registry error on clients by updating the docker registry server

Tags: docker, docker-registry

When upgrading to docker 1.3 the docker client produced the following error:

```
... 
If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry <my registry>` to the daemon's arguments.
...
```

This registry is behind our company's firewall, so I do not wish to add any security. Is there a way to remove this error at the registry server? What is the simplest way to do this? Is it enabling https or is there a simpler trick?

I do not want to update the config for all the registry clients

Answer (score 1):

You have to use https if you want to to avoid this warning. Also you need a certificate signed by a known CA. Docker is trying to force security by this.

The other possibility is to use `--insecure-registry` when using the client.

Comment: How do you enable https?

Comment: You can put the registry behind a reverse-proxy. Then the reverse proxy can do the https.

Comment: I use my own nginx-registry for this https://github.com/larrycai/nginx-registry . ordered a certificate signed by a known CA as @DavidSchilling suggested to make user more easy